# Django Cannot find cursor object in connection object

Tags: django, python-3.x, connection

I am developing a web application using django. I am new Django.
I have call a stored procedure from my application. I gone through the django documentation and i found out that using cursor object i can call the procedure. But i cannot find the cursor object in connection object.

This is how my code looks like :

```
from django.db import connection

cursor = connection.cursor()
```

But i cannot find cursor object itself in the connection.

Please help me out where i am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anything wrong with the code you post, I'll assume you don't know how to proceed after you have the cursor, so this is an [example](http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/django_python_stored_procedures.aspx):

```
from django.db import models  
from django.db import connection  


class Document(models.Model):  
    # fields  
    url = models.CharField(max_length=900)  
    content = models.TextField()  
    title = models.TextField()  

    # static method to perform a fulltext search  
    @staticmethod  
    def search(search_string):  
        # create a cursor  
        cur = connection.cursor()  
        # execute the stored procedure passing in   
        # search_string as a parameter  
        cur.callproc('searcher_document_search', [search_string,])  
        # grab the results  
        results = cur.fetchall()  
        cur.close()  


    # wrap the results up into Document domain objects   
    return [Document(*row) for row in results]
```

Comment: I could not even create a cursor object.

Comment: Are you running that code as part of your Django app?

Comment: Yes. I opened source code of connection and its a instance of `DefaultConnectionProxy` (`connection = DefaultConnectionProxy()`). And in DefaultConnectionProxy class here is no cursor and that class does not inherit from any other class

Comment: Have you configured a default database in your settings.py file? How are you exactly running that code?

Comment: I can find the call proc method in `from django.db.backends.utils import CursorWrapper` this package. Is this correct?

Comment: Let me ask you a very important question, what version of Django are you using?

Comment: django version 2.1.5

Comment: Yes i have database connection in setting. Through model (ORM) i can connect and fetch but to call a procedure  i cannot find the cursor object

Comment: It should be working, I can only recommend you to check your environment very carefully.